# Access session variables across web pages

Tags: php, session-variables

The index.php file of my website reads the URL and load the requested page accordingly. So when another page is requested, it is again redirected to index.php and then the requested page loads. I want the session variable to persisit across all pages. But as it everytime goes to index.php session restarts. How do I solve this.

Index.php contains some code like this:

```
<?php 
    include_once 'util.php';
    $pages = getPage($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $page = $pages[1];

    $domain = getDomain($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

    if ($domain != 'xyz.com') {

        $row = fetchRowFromDomain($domain, $page);
        if($row){
        $details = getDetails($row);
        }
        else{
            //redirection to xyz
            exit();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I dont see any session handling code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the `$_SESSION` variable...

Like this:

```
$userName =  $_SESSION['usr_name'];
$userId = $_SESSION['usr_id'];
```

If you do that, you will be able to get the info out of your session which you chose to store in your sessions.

Let me know if this worked for you!